# Wordpress - how add Home to naviagtion?

Tags: wordpress

How can I add Menu to a website with Home menu in it. I do not want to create the Home page manually in pages. In my example there are no Home menu. When I delete menu from Appearance -> Menu, it appears.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
     'container'       => 'div',
     'container_class' => 'sun-main-nav',    
     'theme_location'  => 'submenu'
     )
   );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you add the Home page link to an existing menu in WordPress.

1. In the WordPress admin go to **Appearance** > **Menus**.
2. Then in **Pages** panel on the left select the **View All** tab.
3. There should be an option there called something like **Home: Home**.
   Check that then click **Add to Menu**.
4. Once the menu item appears, reposition it if necessary, then click the **Save Menu** button.

[Reference from WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen#Pages)